# '404 Page Not Found' every page with codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I used this .htaccess file on my localhost:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

But when I uploaded my site to the ftp, it suddenly doesn't work. I set the base_url. Mod rewrite is enabled. What else can be the problem. My knowledge is very limited, I was already happy, that I programming part, but this server stuff is over my head. But I'm willing to learn it, so if you recommend a place to start, I'm open to that.

So right now only a formatted page comes in, with basic css settings and the 404 message. It's weird, that this message can be created in a form like that, so it means it's not a technical problem, but a settings problem. I googled around, tried more .htaccess files, but nothing works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: By any chance, are you on GoDaddy hosting? CI needs some special settings on GoDaddy.

Comment: No. I tried with two hosting. I had an old site on dotroll and I made a subdomain there, but it didn't work, so I figured, the subdomain was the problem, so I searched for a free hosting just to test it, but the problem is the same.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of free hosting, but anyway ... Can you try removing the htaccess file and accessing the app via full path, like `http://www.example.com/index.php/login/welcome`?

Comment: I figured it out, see my answer below. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is silly. The controllers must be named starting with a big case letter. So the only problem was, that I named my default controller as welcome.php instead of Welcome.php. It was hard to figure out, because it worked on localhost. So this had nothing to do with .htaccess at all. May be valuable to others, so they don't make the same mistake.

Comment: LOL. Yes, such things happen at times ... :)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error when people are using FastCGI - you need to add to the config.php:

$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";

This clicks everything together - Might not be the answer to this issue but worth a try and others with your symptoms may find this useful.

Thanks,
//P